# Passing List / Data table to Inline SQL for inserting data into database without using UDT (user type table)

Tags: sql-server

Requirement : 
1. I am using inline SQL to insert data into the DB table.
2. I have hierarchical lists which I have to pass to inline SQL to insert data into DB table.

How can I pass List / data table to inline SQL to insert data into DB table **with out using UDT (user type table)**

Comment: Please describe more in details what do you need

Comment: Please give us an example of what sort of query you have, you expect to see and what you've tried

Comment: I have to insert data into db table using inline SQLfrom API without using any UDTs. Inline SQL has complex logic and inserts many rows in many db tables. Since I am not using UDTs, currently I am creating dynamic SQL statements in C# like declare SQL table, SQL variable and also SQL inserts statements to insert data in SQL tables. Basically the SQL command is not parameterized and this is open for SQL injection attack and is also failing in cases here in SQL text has any single quote etc.